# How do i ignore the space in command line input in python

Tags: python, append, command-line-arguments

So i need to append to a file in python. This is a random command line input

Example 1:

```
file1 This is a sentence.
```

How do i make it so it "This is a sentence" would be appended to file1 not just "This"

Example 2:

```
file2 A sentence
```

How do i make it so it "A sentence" would be appended to file2 not just "A"

This is what i have so far. And any random sentence could be appended to the files

```
with open(input[1],'a') as fileA:
        fileA.write(input[2])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the second command line arguments as a single argument in the shell:

```
python /path/to/script.py file1 "This is a sentence."
```

Alternatively, join the arguments after the filename using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
with open(input[1], 'a') as fileA:
    fileA.write(' '.join(input[2:]))
```

But the alternative solution will not preserve exact count of spaces / tabs.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck for ages!